# why is flutter refusing to connect on localhost:8000 or 127.0.01:8000?

Tags: rest, api, flutter

I'm following the Flutter Networking/HTTP tutorial to do a GET request to a server running on my localhost:8000. Visiting my localhost via my browser works fine. This works fine too when I point to any real URL, such as https://example.com, but when I point to https://127.0.0.1:8000 I get an error like " connection refused "

The port in the error above changes each time I reload the app. I looked in the http package code and it doesn't seem like there is a way to specify the port for the URL. How do I point to my localhost please it's my first time with flutter ?
PS: i'm running on my phone device , my pc and phone are connected with the same wifi, my network is private.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  static const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/membres/';

  // static const url = 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/membres/';
  //static const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/membres/';
  //static const url= "192.168.1...:8000/association/api/membres";
  //static const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _future = fetch();
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetch() {
    return http
        .get(url)
        .then((response) {
          return response.statusCode == 200
              ? response.body
              : throw 'Error when getting data';
        })
        .then((body) => json.decode(body))
        .then((list) => (list as List).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async {
          _future = fetch();
          setState(() {});
          return _future;
          },
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          future: _future,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),),),);}
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );}
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final item = snapshot.data[index];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(item['name']),
                  subtitle: Text(item['email']),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: check your laptop's local IP using the command `ipconfig` for Windows or `ifconfig` for mac/linux. Use that IP instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1. These address are loopback addresses for the devices they are being accessed from.

Comment: Also the port in the error is not the server port that you are connecting to but the client port. This value changes every time because the system picks a random port from available ports to make the request.

Comment: how to do it please ? i'm already have triedwith my ip adress but it return an error also  `static const url= "192.168.1.102:8000/association/api/membres"; ` ==> No route to host, errno = 113, address=192.168.1.102 , port = 46862

Comment: are you using mac, windows or linux?

Comment: i'm using windows and i've changed my network to private

Comment: or just see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779992/10336633) and if it doesn't work then ask here.

Comment: it doesn't work,

Comment: check your phone and computer network you have to keep same network those then add computer ip address

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to keep your **mobile phone and computer same network** connection.

then pass your url assuming your ip and url is this `192.168.1.102:8000`

```
static const url= "192.168.1.102:8000/association/api/membres";
```

Answer (score 48):

If you are using an Android emulator then `localhost` on the emulator is not `127.0.0.0` it is `10.0.2.2`, so, on Android emulator you need to write `https://10.0.2.2:8000`, the `https://127.0.0.1:8000` will not work on real device too. because `localhost` means something different on real device.

For more information on how to connect a Flutter app to `localhost` on emulator or on a real device click on the link [Connecting Flutter application to Localhost](https://medium.com/@podcoder/connecting-flutter-application-to-localhost-a1022df63130)

Answer (score 3):

Note: Please set your network as "Home Network". Setting the network as Home Network means that you are allowing your PC to share stuff with other devices on the same network.

If you are using Windows 10, this can be done with the following:

Open Settings
Go to Network & Internet
Select WiFi in the left menu
Tap on the name of the connected WiFi
Set the Network Profile of the network to be Private
If you are having an issue, it is most likely to do with Windows Firewall.

Open Control Panel
Go to Windows Defender Firewall
Tap on Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall
Check whether the app is enabled for Private networks (there should be a tick)
If it is not enabled, tap Change settings and tick the checkbox under Private for the app

Answer (score 2):

In window 10 Open Settings go to network and internet setting after that click on Wifi on left side after that Click on your connected Wifi after that change Network Profile from public to private now your real devices will call apis you want to call from server

Answer (score 1):

This one work for me (i use)

$: adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080