# Cannot send http request from Flutter to Flask

Tags: python, flutter, dart, flask

i'm trying to make a simple request to Flask but i keep getting connection refused.

This is my `main.py`

```
import os
import sys
from konlpy.tag import Kkma, Hannanum, Okt
from flask import Flask, jsonify
sys.stdin.reconfigure(encoding="utf-8")
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding="utf-8")


app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return jsonify({'message': 'Hello, world!'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I started and got this message

```
* Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

And on Flutter:

```
  final String baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';

  void _search() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl));
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

I was reading this:
[why is flutter refusing to connect on localhost:8000 or 127.0.01:8000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55908089/why-is-flutter-refusing-to-connect-on-localhost8000-or-127-0-018000)

I'm using the android emulator, i also tried making the request to `https://10.0.2.2:5000`, but still didn't work. I also tried on my real device and got the same thing.

My computer is connected to the internet via cable, so maybe that's something to consider.

Thanks

Comment: checkout this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network)

Answer (score 0):

From the flutter side you are using the wrong endpoint
Change you baseurl from

```
  final String baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';
```

To

```
  final String baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/';
```